# Give the number digits

Tags: java, android

I have a problem:

I would like to declare my number format so here is the example:

I have this number 45.23463 and I would like to convert like this:

0045.23463000000

After the dots are ok couse i us the string.format("%.8f",variable); But what about before the dot?

Thx afruther for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a `DecimalFormat` instance, with a `0` character for every spot that must show a digit, even if it's a leading/trailing zero.

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0000.00000000000");
```

Then call [`format`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#format%28double%29) to format the number.

The [Javadocs for `DecimalFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) contain a list of formatting symbols you can use here.